# Name of a plastic piece on a VW Jetta on front and back door

Tags: part-identification, jetta

I have a 2007 Volkswagen Jetta. She has an approximately **5 inch wide plastic piece on the front and back doors**.

These are faded now and would like to replace them. I wanted to research whether I can buy these and fix them myself or if I have to take my car into the shop. I have no clue what these pieces are called to even do research on them.

Here is exactly what I am looking for. I got this picture from Google but drew the red square myself :)

[image]

What is this plastic piece called? Is it simple to replace myself?

Comment: It's probably called a "b-pillar cover" but I don't know for sure. There are products on the market which would revitalize this, and would be a lot cheaper than replacement. Just saying ...

Answer (score 4):

There are several products which would probably be, not only easier, but work better than painting. These products include such things as [Black Wow](http://www.autogeek.net/black-wow-trim-restorer.html), [303 products](http://www.goldeagle.com/brands/303-products), or even [Meguiars Ultimate Black](http://www.autogeek.net/meguiars-ultimate-black.html?productid=meguiars-ultimate-black&channelid=FROOG&utm_source=CSEs&utm_medium=GoogleProductSearch&utm_campaign=CSE&gclid=CO_22aCykr8CFdBi7AodYz8Amw). I personally would take the course of least resistance, namely: 1) try one of these products, 2) painting the pieces, and then 3) replacement if all else fails. Why do more work than you need to get the result you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can buy a can of matte or satin finish paint and simply spray them. The best option is to remove them completely, spray, and then put them back. You don't want to get paint on your windows or panels. Otherwise, you'll want to use masking tape and newspaper and thoroughly cover every surface around the part you want to spray.

Those things, and any other piece of flimsy plastic replacement part is often ridiculously expensive when bought from the manufacturer. It's usually not worth replacing it unless your insurance offers to cough up the dough.

Answer (score 1):

It is often referred to as B Pillar Vinyl - cause that is what it is... vinyl.
You can hardly remove it without destroying it, because it is (most likely) glued to the B pillar (had the issue with an Audi)

see amazon for custom made vinyl foils: https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=b+pillar+vinyl+jetta&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Ab+pillar+vinyl+jetta